# Kubuntu application-specific font dpi settings?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts, gui, display-resolution

I'm running Kubuntu on 1920x1080 screen resolution. Due to large fonts in some applications (Gwenview, Dolphin), I have set Force Fonts DPI in System Settings -> Fonts to 96 DPI. However, now i'm experiencing tiny and barely visible gui elements on some other apps, like Python IDLE. Is there any possible solution to this, or is there a way I can force different settings for dpi per application?

Answer (score 0):

I found such a way, though it is not very clean. I simply changed the file `/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6/ttk/fonts.tcl` on my system:

```
--- fonts.tcl.bk        2016-12-02 10:40:58.313926142 +0000
+++ fonts.tcl   2016-12-02 10:44:23.591285739 +0000
@@ -131,10 +131,10 @@
            set F(family) "Helvetica"
            set F(fixed)  "courier"
        }
-       set F(size) -12
-       set F(ttsize) -10
-       set F(capsize) -14
-       set F(fixedsize) -12
+       set F(size) 10
+       set F(ttsize) 9
+       set F(capsize) 12
+       set F(fixedsize) 10

        font configure TkDefaultFont -family $F(family) -size $F(size)
        font configure TkTextFont    -family $F(family) -size $F(size)
```

It seems that the defaults for X are given in pixels (negative numbers) rather than points (positive numbers), which is the root of the problem.